# Do electrical junction boxes in the attic that are mounted above the insulation and on the roof truss require a cover plate?

Tags: attic, junction

Do attic junction boxes require a cover plate?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, every box requires a cover plate.  You can't have a cavity with individual wires and wirenuts enjoying a view of the attic.

And a steel box needs a steel cover plate.

Blank cover plates are readily available for less than a buck. There are only a few styles and sizes and I just keep one or two on hand.

Comment: I honestly don't mean to be disagreeable, but can you quote chapter+verse on the statement "...steel box needs steel plate"? It's new to me and I'm always trying to learn.

Comment: This falls in the basic umbrellas of:  parts must be listed (tested to standards - UL), NEC 110.2.  Must be used as designed, NEC 110.3. Neat and workmanlike manner, 110.12. The cover requirement itself is right next door, 110.12a, and requires the cover to have substantially the same protection as the box or better, i.e. metal > plastic.